# Edit home page products in magento template

Tags: magento

http://themeforest.net/item/gala-electronues-market-responsive-theme/full_screen_preview/4138219 This is the magento template i am using for my website. i want to add "add to cart" in all my products in homepage.where and what to edit??

Comment: Hello you will call addtocart html into your template <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>

Answer (score 0):

for find where to edit you can use magento default functionality by enabling that
go to

```
system->configuration->developer->debug
```

(you have to change your store from dropdown on top left). Here you can enable the Template Path Hints. By doing this you can get the path from where is it rendering.

and for the add to cart button try this

```
 <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
```